# How to interface MIPI DSI with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, programming, interface, tft

I'd like to learn about interfacing a TFT LCD with a microcontroller via the MIPI DSI protocol and writing a program for it.

Both have suitable number of pins, some microcontrollers support MIPI DSI while others don't.

Where can I start and what should I do?

Comment: Start by using an SoC which supports MIPI DSI (which is probably a bit more than a “microcontroller”). Note that there are variants of MIPI DSI, especially regarding the number of channels.

Answer (score 1):

MIPI-DSI is a specialized interface intended to drive displays (Display Serial Interface).

It has low-voltage high-speed differential signaling with a low power mode where the differential signals are used in common-mode.

Very few conventional microcontrollers support MIPI-DSI and even fewer support bidirectional capability.

The equivalent interface for input of data is MIPI-CSI (Camera Serial Interface).

The extremely high rate would also be an issue for most processors, speeds of 500Mbps to 2GBps per lane are common.

Comment: So MIPI can't be used with microcontrollers then?

Comment: @akshaykumark - Not what I would call a microcontroller no. Large SOCs, such as in cell phones, use MIPI for communication with the display and camera. I don't know of any smaller devices.

Answer (score 0):

ST Microelectronics makes an eval board for the STM32F469 with a bunch of fun peripherals, including a display and touchscreen.  It's not terribly expensive, either, depending on your means.

https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-discovery-kits/32f469idiscovery.html

Comment: This is what I had. My apologies if I had provided too little information.

Comment: So are you looking for software guidance then?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anything even about RGB or LVDS interfacing. I can only do SPI and dot matrix displays.

Comment: I can interface the pins accordingly, that's as much the hardware I can do..